# How can I join two queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can i join these two queries (Query1-Query2)

#### Query1:

```
declare @date1 datetime,@date2 datetime , @COUNT INT , @countgap int
seLECT @date1='2009-05-11' , @date2 = '2009-05-12'
seLECT @countgap = 30 , @COUNT = 0 

select @date1 TARIH , @COUNT SIRA 
INTO #TMP
WHILE @date1 < @date2 
BEGIN 
    SELECT  @date1 = DATEadd(minute,@countgap,@date1) , @COUNT = @COUNT +1
    INSERT INTO #TMP
    select @date1 TARIH , @COUNT SIRA 
END
SELECT TARIH , SIRA , ( 0) VISITINGCOUNT 
FROM #TMP
ORDER BY SIRA
```

---

#### Query2  :

```
select count(page) as TARIH,   
    (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap  as SIRA 
    from scr_SecuristLog  
    where Date between @date1  and  @date2 
    GROUP BY (datepart(hour,Date)*60+datepart(minute,Date))/@countgap
```

Look please 'SIRA'. This Column equals in two datatable. 
Run Query1 look result please. i need inner join two table

#### Query1 Result

```
2009-05-11 00:00:00.000 0   0

.

.

.

.

.

2009-05-11 07:00:00.000 14  0

2009-05-11 07:30:00.000 15  0

2009-05-11 08:00:00.000 16  0

2009-05-11 08:30:00.000 17  0

2009-05-11 09:00:00.000 18  0

2009-05-11 09:30:00.000 19  0

2009-05-11 10:00:00.000 20  0

2009-05-11 10:30:00.000 21  0

2009-05-11 11:00:00.000 22  0

2009-05-11 11:30:00.000 23  0

2009-05-11 12:00:00.000 24  0

2009-05-11 12:30:00.000 25  0

2009-05-11 13:00:00.000 26  0

2009-05-11 13:30:00.000 27  0

2009-05-11 14:00:00.000 28  0

2009-05-11 14:30:00.000 29  0

2009-05-11 15:00:00.000 30  0

2009-05-11 15:30:00.000 31  0

2009-05-11 16:00:00.000 32  0

2009-05-11 16:30:00.000 33  0

2009-05-11 17:00:00.000 34  0

2009-05-11 17:30:00.000 35  0

2009-05-11 18:00:00.000 36  0

.

.

.
```

#### Query2 Result

```
3   23
9   29
10  32
3   21
18  33
```

#### i need  Result

```
2009-05-11 00:00:00.000 0   0

....

2009-05-11 07:00:00.000 14  0

2009-05-11 07:30:00.000 15  0

2009-05-11 08:00:00.000 16  0

2009-05-11 08:30:00.000 17  0

2009-05-11 09:00:00.000 18  33

2009-05-11 09:30:00.000 19  0

2009-05-11 10:00:00.000 20  0

2009-05-11 10:30:00.000 21  0

2009-05-11 11:00:00.000 22  0

2009-05-11 11:30:00.000 23  3

2009-05-11 12:00:00.000 24  0

2009-05-11 12:30:00.000 25  0

2009-05-11 13:00:00.000 26  0

2009-05-11 13:30:00.000 27  0

2009-05-11 14:00:00.000 28  0

2009-05-11 14:30:00.000 29  9

2009-05-11 15:00:00.000 30  0

2009-05-11 15:30:00.000 31  0

2009-05-11 16:00:00.000 32  10

2009-05-11 16:30:00.000 33  0

2009-05-11 17:00:00.000 34  0

2009-05-11 17:30:00.000 35  0

2009-05-11 18:00:00.000 36  0

...
```

Comment: What is your desired result??

Comment: Yes, we need to know what you are trying to achieve before we can offer suggestions.

Comment: i add new version one. Please look above......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit tricky, as the field names doesn't match between the tables...

```
select t1.TARIH, t1.SIRA, VISITINGCOUNT = isnull(t2.SIRA, 0)
from #TMP t1
left join ( --paste query 2 here-- ) t2 on t2.TARIH = t1.SIRA
order by t1.SIRA
```